# class java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to class org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap

Tags: java, rest

I want to generate a JSON response which includes inner JSON Objects. I tried this:

```
public Map<String, Object> getCountryNameCodeList() {

        String[] countryCodes = Locale.getISOCountries();
        Map<String, Object> list = new HashMap<>();

        for (String countryCode : countryCodes) {

            Locale obj = new Locale("", countryCode);

            list.put(obj.getDisplayCountry().toString(), obj.getCountry());
        }

        return list;
    }
```

Rest Api:

```
@GetMapping("shipping_countries")
    public ResponseEntity<Set<Map.Entry<String, Object>>> getShippingCountries() {

        Map<String, Object> list = countriesService.getCountryNameCodeList();

        List<KeyValueDTO> dtos = new ArrayList();
        for(Map.Entry<String, Object> value: list.entrySet()) {
            KeyValueDTO dto = new KeyValueDTO();
            dto.setKey(value.getKey());
            dto.setValue(value.getValue().toString());
            dtos.add(dto);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<Set<Map.Entry<String, Object>>>((MultiValueMap<String, String>) dtos, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

I want to get this response:

```
[
  {
    name: "Papua New Guinea",
    value: "PG"
  },
  {
    name: "Unites States",
    value: "US"
  }, 
  ....
]
```

But I get this error:

```
class java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to class org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap (java.util.ArrayList is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader @6267c3bb)
```

How I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are typecasting `List<KeyValueDTO>` a list into `(MultiValueMap<String, String>)` a multimap. They are totally different types - a list is not a map. Hence, the exception in your post. Try to return the value without the cast.